# Are there any machine learning regression algorithms that can train on ordinal data?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I have a function f(x): R^n --> R (sorry, is there a way to do LaTeX here?), and I want to build a machine learning algorithm that estimates f(x) for any input point x, based on a bunch of sample xs in a training data set. If I know the value of f(x) for every x in the training data, this should be simple - just do a regression, or take the weighted average of nearby points, or whatever.

However, this isn't what my training data looks like. Rather, I have a bunch of pairs of points (x, y), and I know the value of f(x) - f(y) for each pair, but I don't know the absolute values of f(x) for any particular x. It seems like there ought to be a way to use this data to find an approximation to f(x), but I haven't found anything after some Googling; there are papers like [this](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~eibe/pubs/ordinal_tech_report.pdf) but they seem to assume that the training data comes in the form of a set of discrete labels for each entity, rather than having labels over pairs of entities.

This is just making something up, but could I try kernel density estimation over f'(x), and then do integration to get f(x)? Or is that crazy, or is there a known better technique?

Comment: Do you expect many overlapping values? i.e., do you have many occurences of `(x, y, f(x)-f(y)) ; (x, z, f(x)-f(z))`? What do you know about your function (is it differentiable etc.)? Is there anything you can assume about the input at all except what you told us already?

Comment: There might be some overlapping values, but I wouldn't expect a large number of them; eg. there would not be dozens or hundreds of ys for every x. f(x) can be assumed differentiable, but probably won't have a closed-form expression. Not sure what assumptions might be important, but f(x) should mostly be "smooth", in the sense that f(x) <= f(x/2 + y/2) <= f(y) for most pairs x, y (assuming f(x) < f(y)).

Comment: I don't think the question title fits the body so much. Maybe consider revising to attract the experts... (for example, "How can we learn f(x)-f(y) without direct access to f's outputs?".)

Comment: Your problem seems unrelated to "ordinal data". Usually that term means that the features or the label are numeric but are not measurements -- rather they represent some order, perhaps such as low, medium, and high.

Comment: @Alyssa, you write that `f` likely has no closed-form, but you accepted the answer assuming it is linear. I can't tell you what you can tell us, either. :) What is the actual thing you want to achieve? What does `f` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assume that f is linear, which would simplify things - if f is linear we know that:

```
f(x-y) = f(x) - f(y)
```

For example, Suppose you assume f(x) = <w, x>, making w the parameter you want to learn. How would the squared loss per sample (x,y) and known difference d look like?

```
loss((x,y), d) = (f(x)-f(y) - d)^2
               = (<w,x> - <w,y> - d)^2
               = (<w, x-y> - d)^2
               = (<w, z> - d)^2 // where z:=x-y
```

Which is simply the squared loss for z=x-y

Practically, you would need to construct z=x-y for each pair and then learn f using linear regression over inputs z and outputs d.

This model might be too weak for your needs, but its probably the first thing you should try. Otherwise, as soon as you step away from the linearity assumption, you'd likely arrive at a difficult non-convex optimization problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to get absolute results. Any constant in your function (`f(x) = g(x) + c`) will disappear, in the same way constants disappear in an integral.

Comment: Of course, but I could just eg. arbitrarily fix f(x) = 0 when x is the null vector.

Comment: I thought you meant whether you can find the "absolute" values (including the offset). Nevermind this answer then.